# What is the etymology of "BFE"?

Tags: etymology, offensive-language

[BFE](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bfe) is an abbreviation for "Bum Fuck Egypt" or "Butt Fuck Egypt," which is used to denote "out in the middle of nowhere."

I'm curious how this expression came about. [UrbanDictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bfe) has a user-submitted definition with the following etymology:

> As I understand (and other people have corroborated), it derives its existence from another expression “bumble fuck” (I am unsure if it's one word or two), both of which mean "out in the middle of nowhere." I am fairly certain that the inaccurate “butt fuck Egypt” derived from bum being the English term for buttocks. Clearly the definition of BFE is the same regardless of what one believes the “B” stands for, but I thought is was worth correcting.

I have no idea how accurate or reliable the above etymology is. There is no entry on EtymOnline.com.

Comment: A related destination, at least in my mind, was always East Jesus, which I first encountered mid 90s.

Comment: Some language and stories emphasize the forlornness of a place by implying that it's so far from civilization that there are no women around, so men have to deviate from personal norms to achieve sexual satisfaction. So in this instance, this is a corner of Egypt so remote that the only option is to fuck your comrade in the bum. Other examples are when sailors are assigned to Norfolk ("No-Fuck") Virginia, or when isolated settlers of North Dakota became possessive of a lone tree's knothole — "that's MY KNOT!" (Minot, North Dakota).

Answer (score 15):

### Summary

*Bumfuck, Egypt* is first documented in army slang from 1972, and *BFE* is from at least 1988. *Bumfuck, [Egypt]* appears to be the original, followed by variations *Bumblefuck* (1989), *Bubblefuck* (1993) and *Buttfuck* (1999).

Sometimes these variations appear standing alone, sometimes in Egypt, or Africa (also found in *BFA*), or another country, (rural) state or place, and sometimes prefixed by East or West. More recently, both *BFN* and *Butt Fucking Nowhere* are reported from 2002.

As *Bumfuck, Egypt* appears to be originally military slang, given the number of abbreviations they used I can easily believe it was also jocularly and euphemistically shortened to BFA before 1988.

---

### Partridge

*[The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Uncoventional English](http://books.google.com/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PA50&dq=BFE+slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yJ2mUNDUAbD54QTpsYDwCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bumfuck&f=false)* (2003):

> **BFE** *noun* any remote location. An abbreviation of BUMFUCK, EGYPT *US 1989*
>
> **Bumblefuck** *noun* any remote, small town *US 1989*
>
> **Bumfuck, Egypt** *noun* a mythical town that is the epitome of remoteness. With variants *US 1972*

It also gives *BFN* and *Butt Fucking Nowhere*, both from 2002.

---

### OUP

These 1989 and 1972 first citations are given with others in *[The F-Word](http://books.google.com/books?id=I_AGK-49nlcC&pg=PA1930&dq=BFE+slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yJ2mUNDUAbD54QTpsYDwCA&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=BFE%20&f=false)* (2009, Oxford University Press):

> **BFE** *noun* [*B*umfuck (or *B*umbfuck), *E*gypt]
>
> > *Military & Students*. a very remote place; the middle of nowhere.
> >
> > **1989** P. Munro *U.C.L.A. Slang* 20: Troy...lives out in B.F.E....*Bum Fuck, Egypt*.
>
> **Bumfuck** *noun*
>
> > *Military & Students*. a very remote place. --used with a placename, esp. in **Bumfuck, Egypt**. Also **Bumfuckistan**. *Jocular.* See also BFE, BUMBLEFUCK.
> >
> > **1972** Sgt. E-6, U.S. Army: They probably sent those records out to Bumfuck, Egypt.

It also gives *Bumblefuck* as a 1989 alteration of *Bumfuck*; *Bubblefuck* as a 1993 alteration of *Bumblefuck*; and *Buttfuck*, usually used with a placename, from 1999.

---

### Usenet

I found an earlier example for the initials *BFE* in Usenet, on [11th September 1988](https://groups.google.com/group/alt.cyberpunk/browse_thread/thread/17c95c80a2819fe2/d99d26437130e9aa?q=BFE#d99d26437130e9aa) in alt.cyberpunk:

> $600 is about what we paid for my first computer -- a C64, 1541 and printer; when I was a upper-lower class kid living in the backwoods of 
>   BFE, Leesville, Louisiana.  (Ft. Polk sux too. :-).  We weren't on 
>   welfare, but we weren't rich either.  I think we saved about 9-12months 
>   for the computer.  (Grandparents bought me a monitor a month later. What 
>   a rescue. :-).  That computer made the difference between me being 
>   a dual major CompSci/Journalism student in Houston instead of being 
>   like my cousins:  2-4 kids, HS diploma at best, slow paying job, no future, 
>   and living in BFE, Louisiana.

Answer (score 8):

There was a time when one would have simply said "[Podunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podunk)" to mean "the middle of nowhere". Some time after [*Deliverance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deliverance), and, not coincidentally, during a time when vulgarity began to be a more regular feature of comic acts, the exact geometric centre of nowhere became a fictional hamlet called Buttfuck, <insert poor or "backward" Southern State> (often Tennessee or Arkansas).

Lately, though, and especially in light of the Gulf Wars and 9/11, the Islamic world has become the target of choice for pejoratives. Buttfuck was moved from the territory of the hill folk to somewhere a little less offensive to people living south of the Mason-Dixon line. The cultural origin of the original fictional town (the famous "squeal like a pig" scene) was lost, but the idea of backward sodomites in a foreign world survived the translation.

As for the abbreviation, well, that's something that tends to happen quickly in the world of SMS and tweets. If something occurs frequently and requires more than a couple of characters, somebody is going to abbreviate it.

Comment: Your analysis makes sense, but I remember this term being popular when I was in high school, which was in the mid-90s - long before text messaging and pre-dating 9/11 and Gulf War II.

Comment: I was in the military during Gulf War I -- trust me, the hate and propaganda was thick in the air, and it wasn't all about Iraq.

Comment: @bye: Um, so?  Just because there was anti-Arab sentiment then doesn't mean that that's when the phrase originated.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an better explanation than Stan for the "butt-fuck" part (I'd always heard it as "bum-fuck", which made me think it was originally British) but it certainly ante-dates the First Gulf War.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name) suggests that "Egypt" was originally a Chicago-area expression referring to the [southern third of Illinois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Egypt_%28region%29#Origin_of_.22Little_Egypt.22_name), especially the towns of Cairo, Thebes, and Karnak.

Answer (score 2):

I know for certain we used "BFE" when I was back in high school too prior to 1989 and therefore, well before even the first Gulf War.  Interestingly enough, some time later, when I moved Hyde Park, NY., which is just north on the Hudson above Poughkeepsie, NY.,  I had the local expression "up in Poughkeepsie" explained to me.  It was immediately likened to what they called the "midwestern" expression "BFE".  Basically, if one was hopelessly lost, it was said they were "up in Poughkeepsie."

Poughkeepsie is and has always been the last stop on the New York City Metro Train Line.  Historically, as it was explained, New York City mobsters, criminals, etc. looking to get "lost" would take the metro line's anonymous ticket ride up to Poughkeepsie, disperse into the countryside, and hide out from the law.  This notion of this tradition is apparently still popular today, as it was duplicated, more or less, in a later episode of the Sopranos.

As previously suggested, the vulgarity and the proximity to Chicago of Cairo, Thebes, and Karnak, Illinois would lend some creedence to the Wikipedia suggestion that the "BFE" expression might have similarly arose among mobsters, criminals, or anyone looking to "hide out" outside the Chicago area.  It seems very logical to think that if a mobster, etc. said "so and so is hiding out in BFE", they were speaking in code about taking the train to St. Louis and hiding out across the river in southern Illinois.  Something else that lends some creedence to this suggestion is that if one proceeds to the very tip of southern Illinois and ultimately crosses the Ohio River, one would end up in Paducah (Podunk), Kentucky.  Paducah is 373 miles from Chicago, 140 miles from St. Louis, MO, 140 miles from Memphis, TN and 120 miles from Nashville, TN and thus would truly have been, in the 1920s and 30s, in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: I second that, I grew up in Pittsburgh, PA, and I remember first hearing "BFE" to describe the Boonies in the very early 80's

Comment: @Tas I guessed which answer you were commenting on. I can move it to a different one if I guessed wrong. Just ping me.

Comment: @KitFox: Normally, comments-as-answers were meant for the lowest voted answer, as the "Your answer" box usually appears immediately below it. So, before my [new answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/91490/9001), it would have been [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54011/9001).

Answer (score 2):

When I was working in the oil patch in Wyoming in the early 1970's we used the term BFE to refer to any remote location we had to go to work. Example: "Where did you go today? We were in Bum Fuck Egypt (BFE) and got lost out there looking for Amoco's well head #21."  It just seemed like maybe Egypt had some pretty big expanses of remote desert, and there were definitely a lot of those remote desert type regions we all had to cross to find some remote oil field location.